# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'endsWith')

Tags: javascript, sorting

*I am trying to print out all countries which end with 'land' from the countries array below:*

```
const countries = [
  'Albania',
  'Bolivia',
  'Canada',
  'Denmark',
  'Ethiopia',
  'Finland',
  'Germany',
  'Hungary',
  'Ireland',
  'Japan',
  'Kenya'
]

newArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i <= countries.length; i++){
  console.log(countries[i])
  if (countries[i].endsWith('land') === true){
    newArr.push(countries[i])
  }
  else{
    continue
  }
}
```

*However, I am having a TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'endsWith)*

Comment: `i < countries.length` instead of `i <= countries.length`

Comment: `i <= countries.length` makes the loop try to access the element `countries[countries.length]` which doesnt exist

Comment: You are trying to access one more country than there is in the array - remember arrays in JS start with index 0 o the last one has index length-1 so convert your <= to <.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I have a better understanding now!

Answer (score 0):

out of index
try this

```
for (let i = 0; i <= countries.length - 1; i++) {
    console.log(countries[i]);
    if (countries[i].endsWith("land") === true) {
        newArr.push(countries[i]);
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `=` because index will be one less than the array length!

```js
const countries = [
  'Albania',
  'Bolivia',
  'Canada',
  'Denmark',
  'Ethiopia',
  'Finland',
  'Germany',
  'Hungary',
  'Ireland',
  'Japan',
  'Kenya'
]

newArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < countries.length; i++){
  console.log(countries[i])
  if (countries[i].endsWith('land') === true){
    newArr.push(countries[i])
  }
  else{
    continue
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have already got the answer from comments and other answers, but here is few improvement you can do using array `reduce` and `&&`

```js
const countries = [
  'Albania',
  'Bolivia',
  'Canada',
  'Denmark',
  'Ethiopia',
  'Finland',
  'Germany',
  'Hungary',
  'Ireland',
  'Japan',
  'Kenya'
]

const z = countries.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  curr.endsWith('land') && acc.push(curr);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a few changes to improve your loop

```js
countries = ["finland", "ireland", "australia", "italy"];
newArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    // < countries.length instead of <= countries.length - 1
    if (countries[i].endsWith("land")) { // Don't need === true
        newArr.push(countries[i]);
    } // don't need "else continue"
}

console.log(newArr);
```

And you can also use the inbuilt [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to do the same thing.

```js
const countries = [
  'Albania',
  'Bolivia',
  'Canada',
  'Denmark',
  'Ethiopia',
  'Finland',
  'Germany',
  'Hungary',
  'Ireland',
  'Japan',
  'Kenya'
]

const newArray = countries.filter(country => country.endsWith('land'));

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because in the for loop you took i<=countries.length it should be i<countries.length.

```
const countries = [
'Albania',
'Bolivia',
'Canada',
'Denmark',
'Ethiopia',
'Finland',
'Germany',
'Hungary',
'Ireland',
'Japan',
'Kenya'
]
newArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i <countries.length; i++){
   if(countries[i].endsWith('land'))
   newArr.push(countries[i]);
}   
for(let i=0; i<newArr.length; i++){
   console.log(newArr[i]);
}
```